# How to apply multiple styles to HTML to only part of a title?

Tags: html, css, inline, styling

So I have a some text "only 3 days left"
Which I what to make the color #EF5F3C
and also to made bold too. An to ignore the styling for the rest of sentence.

Image example of what I am trying to acheive:

[image: screenshot of expected rensult]

I have tried using multiple inline style to style the HTML which does work for colour, font-size etc but not strong or em.

```html
<div class="copy">
  <h6> <span style="color:#EF5F3C;"><strong>Only 3 days left</strong></span> to fund this project</h6>
  <p>Join the <strong>42 </strong> other donors who have already supported this project. Every dollar helps</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the font-weight and font-style properties.

Answer (score 2):

The `h6` is already bold by default.

I made and example where you can see it with `h6` and a regular paragraph `p` tag.

[image]

```css
h6 span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF5F3C;
}

p span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF5F3C;
}
```

```html
<h6><span>Only 3 days left</span> to fund this project</h6>

<p><span>Only 3 days left</span> to fund this project</p>
```